# QuickFIX/J - performance benchmark

Tags: java, benchmarking, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am in the team responsible for developemnt quickfix, unfortunately I don't have much experience with it and I'm learning so far.

Suppose I have a quickfixj server where I have my own logic and now I would like to test its load.

Are there any tools I could use for these tasks. Are there any external libraries or frameworks that I could use?

For now, I do it myself, putting a stub server and generating orders, e.g. every few milliseconds and waiting for a response, e.g. ExecutionReport. Then I compare the time between sending the order from the stub and the response to the execution report?

```
SendingTime <52>
```

What do you think about it?

Comment: I suppose your server and your client are on the same machine or are time-synchronised? Otherwise it would be problematic to compare the time stamps.

Comment: yes, on the sam machine, thanks for Your answer Christoph :))

Comment: No problem, I don't think I can give more advice than that. I never checked out tools to benchmark QFJ and most probably there is no *specific* tool to do it. If you find something let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways you can feed QuickFix API with messages. You could program it to read files from a directory and do something with them. Or you could program it to read a database table of messages. Or you could hook it up to an in memory grid API to feed it messages. Or you could write NUnit or JUnit tests that call it as a library.

As for a tool, for C# or Java apps I put [StopWatches](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) in the code and use these to generate load reports.